# Do the rules of wudu apply for online reading?

Tags: halal-haram, quran

For example: if I commit a major impurity, is it ok for me to read online? How about minor impurities?

Comment: How should the rules for wudu' apply when ghusl is necessary? They wouldn't be sufficient... Your wording is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Always having youself and your soul clean through Wudu is encouraged. But while reading Quran in online, it is not probably necessary.